# How can I make a Google Sheet script run reliably on Samsung tablets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, samsung-mobile

I have two functions in my Google Sheet script which are each triggered by means of a checkbox (since Google Sheets on mobile can't use images as buttons). They work on PC (rather slowly), but on tablets, they tend to fail more often than not, which then also affects PC users.

The script is set up to perform an onEdit check of two checkbox cells. If the checkbox in cell C3 is checked, the AUTOFILL function should run (which displays the A cell value of the last row on the Info sheet plus 1 in cell C4 of the Data Entry sheet, and then clears the checkbox), and if the checkbox in cell C12 is checked, the SUBMIT function should run (which takes the range of data entered on the Data Entry sheet and updates an existing row/adds a new row on the Data sheet with the information from the Data Entry sheet, adding a timestamp if cell C11 on the Data Entry sheet contains the word 'CLEANED', and then clears the checkbox).

I've tried experimenting with various WIFI signal strengths and more powerful tablets, but I am unable to pinpoint the exact culprit here - sometimes this will run, most often the checkbox will just remain checked and nothing happens. Laptops and desktop computers all seem to run, but if a tablet tries to run and fails, the computers will sometimes not run either, until I go into the script itself and manually force once of the functions to run, which seems to reset things and lets the computers work again.

Is it because of the processing required in order to run this code? I've tried to optimize it as much as possible, but is there something else that I might change here which would make this work, every time?

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15k6Z1wV4u_YlN5Qx9DS_6N1392rkOhom-HlX7S4uiDw/edit?usp=sharing) is the example sheet, and here is the script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != "Data Entry") {
       return
   }

  var isAutofill = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C3").getValue();
  var isSubmit = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C12").getValue();

    if (isAutofill && isSubmit) {
    Browser.msgBox("You cannot autofill and submit data at the same time!");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C3").setValue(false);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C12").setValue(false);
  } else if (isAutofill) {
    AUTOFILL();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C3").setValue(false);
  } else if (isSubmit) {
    SUBMIT();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C12").setValue(false);
  }
}


function AUTOFILL() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Info');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data Entry');
  var valueOfData = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
  sheet2.getRange('C4').setValue(valueOfData + 1);
} 


function SUBMIT() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Data Entry");
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Info");

var values = formSS.getRange("C4:C11").getValues().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
});
var partNum = values[0];
var row;
dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues().forEach(function(r, i) {
    if (r[0] === partNum) {
        row = i + 1
    }
})
row = row ? row : dataSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
var data = dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 8).getValues()[0].map(function (el, ind){
  return el = values[ind] ? values[ind] : el;
  })

var statusValue = formSS.getRange("C11").getValue();

if (statusValue != 'CLEANED') {
dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 8).setValues([data]);
}

if (statusValue == 'CLEANED') {
var now = [new Date()];
var newData =  data.concat(now)
dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 9).setValues([newData]);
}

formSS.getRange("C4:C11").clearContent()
}
```

Comment: You can't use `Browser.msgBox()` in mobile apps

Comment: Thank you, but removing that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: You don't have to keep using `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` over and over  just do this once `var sh=e.range.getSheet()` It a waste of time and you only have 30 seconds to complete onEdit() script.

Comment: Also if you will do this `var rg1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C3");` then you can keep reusing `rg1` in the following commands and save some more time.

Comment: It might be better not to use `forEach` here `dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues().forEach(function(r, i){if(r[0] === partNum) {row = i + 1;}})` because in a for loop you can break it once `r[0]===partNum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes.  Take a look. Hopefully you can use them to speed up the function.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() != "Data Entry") {return;}
  var rgC3=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C3");
  var rgC12=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C12");
  var isAutofill = rgC3.getValue();
  var isSubmit = rgC12.getValue();

  if (isAutofill && isSubmit) {
    e.source.toast("You cannot autofill and submit data at the same time!");
    rgC3.setValue(false);
    rgC12.setValue(false);
  } else if (isAutofill) {
    AUTOFILL(e.source);
    rgC3.setValue(false);
  } else if (isSubmit) {
    SUBMIT(e.source);
    rgC12.setValue(false);
  }
}

function AUTOFILL(ss) {
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Info');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Data Entry');
  var valueOfData = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
  sheet2.getRange('C4').setValue(valueOfData + 1);
} 

function SUBMIT(ss) {
var formSS=ss.getSheetByName("Data Entry");
var dataSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Info");
var values=formSS.getRange("C4:C11").getValues().reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b)});
var partNum = values[0];
var row;
var data=dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
  if(data[i][0]==partNum) {
    row=i+1;
    break;
  }
}
row = row ? row : dataSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
var data = dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 8).getValues()[0].map(function (el, ind){return el = values[ind] ? values[ind] : el;})
var statusValue = formSS.getRange("C11").getValue();
if (statusValue != 'CLEANED') {dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 8).setValues([data]);}
if (statusValue == 'CLEANED') {var now = [new Date()];var newData=data.concat(now);dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 9).setValues([newData]);}
formSS.getRange("C4:C11").clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Whoa, thank you, so far, this seems to be working much better! That's some impressive stuff you did in there. I will do more testing with this and will let you know if this solves the issues I've been having. One question for now, @TheMaster mentioned something about messagebox compatibility - is this something I should remove for higher efficiency, or do you think the time it takes to run the check for both cells is worth keeping for PC users?

Comment: Personally, I would strongly resist putting a modal dialog in an `onEdit()` function.  The `onEdit()` will stop after 30 seconds whether it's done or not.   I actually use the `e.source.toast()` function when I'm testing this sort of function because it's not modal.  But basically I have one opinion about anything "TheMaster" says.  `Consider it wisely because he is probably correct.`

Comment: I've been testing this all week and it seems that optimization was indeed the culprit. Your version allows tablets to run at an almost perfect rate. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I and appreciate hearing back from you and I hope it continues to work well.