# Google Sheets - Start Macro while cell is still open

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

I'm still SUPER new to Google Sheets, I've mostly just programmed in VBA before this.

The project I'm working on is for a D&D type game, wherein the DM will use Sheet to record damage dealt to the monster. Basically the DM types the damage, clicks the calculate button, then the code sums up the current damage to baddie.

The code works perfectly. The problem I'm having is a human one. There is a tendency to click the "calculate" button before closing the cell.

For instance, the DM types 31 in the cell and immediately clicks "calculate" before hitting enter. This prevents the damage from being recorded properly and I can't figure out the code to make the cell close first.

Here is my current code:

```js
function DamageRecordEnemy1Copy1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();

  var DamageLocation = spreadsheet.getRange('Q4');
  var DamageLogLocation = spreadsheet.getRange('Q5');
  var DamageLocationValue = DamageLocation.getValue();
  var DamageLogLocationValue = DamageLogLocation.getValue();
  var NewDamage = DamageLocationValue + DamageLogLocationValue;

  DamageLocation.activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(NewDamage);

  DamageLogLocation.activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue("");
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
}
```

Any idea how to solve the issue? Much appreciated!

Thanks for the help everyone, here is what I ended up doing:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;

  var DamageLocation = spreadsheet.getRange('Q4');
  var DamageLogLocation = spreadsheet.getRange('Q5');
  var DamageLocationValue = DamageLocation.getValue()
  var DamageLogLocationValue = DamageLogLocation.getValue()

  var allRows = [5];
  var allColumns = [17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32];

  var EditRow = range.getRow()
  var EditColumn = range.getColumn()

  if (allColumns.indexOf(EditColumn)  > -1)
  {
      if (allRows.indexOf(EditRow)  > -1)
      {
        var BadDamage = spreadsheet.getRange(EditRow-1,EditColumn)
        var BadDamageLog = spreadsheet.getRange(EditRow,EditColumn)

        var DamageCalc = BadDamage.getValue() + BadDamageLog.getValue()
        BadDamage.setValue(DamageCalc);
        BadDamageLog.setValue("");   
      }
  }  
};
```

Comment: You actually can use circular references and a checkbox to accomplish this without any Script but I would need to see how complicated the sheet is, but my answer pretty much explains how you can use a checkbox instead of a "button" as you know Google Sheets has no button yet unlike Excel so you created a fake button... the checkbox is really the closest thing to a button right now.

Comment: This may be relevant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275794/using-checkboxes-to-trigger-various-scripts-then-clear/58282937#58282937

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the "button" with insert->checkbox then use the OnEdit function to check if that cell was set to true, execute your button code and set it back to false. The reason this will work is because Drawings are on it's own layer but the checkbox will force them to have the "hit enter" behavior.

Comment: This got me on track! I had a hard time wrapping my head around how java manages the onEdit event, but once I got the basis I went a little crazy!

I can't actually paste my new code in here...

I added my code up above, as a fun bonus, thanks for showing me "js" trick with the code!