# Google spreadsheet - Making buttons that add data into cells into another sheet when pressed

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make spreadsheets to keep track of moods and other things. What I want to do is to have a dashboard with buttons with differnt moods that, when pressed, add a value and a specific color to a cell in a second sheet. 
This second sheet will function as a simple database and has the first column with the date (365 rows), and another column with the mood with the colored cells that will be added every time you press the button.

Also, the value when you press the button with the selected mood, must be added next to the row that has the current date.

Summing up:

- I want to make buttons in one sheet
- When you press thos buttons, a specific value is added into another sheet
- That value must be added next to the cell with the current date, in the column with all the dates

I've searched this here, but can't find anything similar. If you can help me directly or posting links to the subject I'll be thankfull.

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting, why do you need this to be a button?

Comment: Because I want to be able to register data from my phone too, and scrolling throughout 8-10 sheets to enter the data into a specific cell is a pain in the @ss.

Comment: If you're looking to use google SS as a BDD, have a look at this : https://github.com/KevAcademyNumerique/GoogleScriptSQL

Comment: That's interesting, I'll check that option later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is in fact quite easy to do with Sheets and Google Apps Scripts. These are the steps:

1. Create a Sheets document.
2. Create a sheet named `database`. Set the headers (i.e.  `A1=Date`, `B1=Mood`).
3. Go to Tools > Script Editor. Paste the following code and save the project:

```js
var TIMEZONE = "GMT";

function wasInserted(date) {
  var lastInsertedDate = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastDate');
  return date == lastInsertedDate;
}

function getDateNow() {
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), TIMEZONE, "M/d/y");
}

function insertMood(mood) {
  var date = getDateNow();
  if (wasInserted(date)) return; // mood already inserted for the day.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('database');
  ss.appendRow([date, mood]);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastDate', date);
}

function selectHappy() {
  insertMood('happy');
}

function selectConfused() {
 insertMood('confused');
}

function selectSad() {
 insertMood('sad');
}
```

4. Create three images in the main sheet of your Sheets document (**important**: they must be "Image over cells"). They must map to Happy, Confused, and Sad, which are the moods that i defined for the application. Of course, you may modify this and add as many moods as you please.
5. Click on each of the pictures, click the three dots and click on "Assign script". For the happy picture, it should be "selectHappy" (see above code - it must map the function names), and so on.

Now, go and test it. click any of the pictures. The first time it will ask you for permissions, which you must accept. Afterwards, you won't be required to accept them. Each time you click them a new entry will be created in the "database" sheet with the selected mood. The buttons can only be clicked once a day, the second time (and so on) will not do anything.

Comment: Really cool, in the comments he mentioned using a mobile device so a work around would be to put a checkbox next to the image and use onEdit(e) to treat the checkbox as a button.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out, CodeCamper. @Huagru you will, as he correctly said, need to use a checkbox as a replacement for the images (as they cannot trigger onClick events from mobile). You can see how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275794/using-checkboxes-to-trigger-various-scripts-then-clear). Additionally, I suggest you check out [WebApps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) which will definitely be more practicable from mobile. If you are interested on that I may be able to post an example tomorrow...

Comment: That's VERY helpful, thank you! I'm still fighting with JavaScript so I'll have to sit down later and see if I can make it work.

Comment: @carlesgg97 I'm new into programming and JavaScript, so I think that WebApps might be a little over my head right now, but I'd saved the link for later, thanks.

Comment: @Huagru just take this answer and combine it with the onEdit link he provided, if you have a problem getting it working post your semi working code as a new question.