# How to copy data to another sheet with a single button click in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01uKQ.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uff35.png)

I'm wondering if anyone could help me create a appscript for terminal invoicing and database purposes? When I click "SUBMIT" as a button in sheet 1 image, it must reflect line by line like in Sheet 2 image. (see sheet 1 image and sheet 2 image)

-after clicking submit it sheet 1 must auto clear

-when I input another set of data after clearing it needs to keep going down line per line in sheet 2

Comment: Hello blueannon. I have provided an answer that should work for you. Kindly let me know if you have any issue with it. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code for that:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // declarations
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('YOUR_SOURCE_SHEET_NAME');
  var database = ss.getSheetByName('YOUR_DATABASE_SHEET_NAME');

  // obtain common variables for each item
  var dateOfOrder = sourceSheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  var dateOfDelivery = sourceSheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var agent = sourceSheet.getRange('B8').getValue();
  var customer = sourceSheet.getRange('B3').getValue();

  // compute variables to initiate reading item rows
  var rows = [];
  var lastItemRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var firstItemRow = 11;
  var nItems = lastItemRow - firstItemRow + 1;

  if (nItems < 1) return;

  // get row-level information and append to database sheet
  var itemNames = sourceSheet.getRange(firstItemRow, 1, nItems, 1).getValues();
  var itemQuantities = sourceSheet.getRange(firstItemRow, 2, nItems, 1).getValues();
  var itemPrices = sourceSheet.getRange(firstItemRow, 3, nItems, 1).getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<nItems; i++) {
    var itemName = itemNames[i][0];
    var itemQuantity = itemQuantities[i][0];
    var itemPrice = itemPrices[i][0];
    database.appendRow([dateOfOrder, dateOfDelivery, agent, customer, itemName,
      itemQuantity, itemPrice, itemQuantity * itemPrice]);
  }

  // clear source sheet
  sourceSheet.getRange("B1:B8").clear();
  sourceSheet.getRange("A11:H").clear();
}
```

The idea is to first obtain data from your source sheet (using `getRange()` along with `getValue()` or `getValues()`) and afterwards insert it using `appendRow()`.

Finally, you can clear the range using the `clear()` method.

In order to create a button that calls this script, I suggest you check out this ([Google spreadsheet - Making buttons that add data into cells into another sheet when pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917820/google-spreadsheet-making-buttons-that-add-data-into-cells-into-another-sheet/58919548#58919548)) other Stackoverflow answer. When assigning the script to the image, the name of it should be "myFunction" (without the quotes).