# I want to be able to click a bid button and make all my bid info on page 1 go to a separate page, one bid per row so i can track better

Tags: google-sheets, button, macros

I wanted to be able to hit a bid button and have all the info on page 1, B1-B8 be put onto a separate page 2, in Row A2-I2... I seen someone ask a similar question: [How to copy data to another sheet with a single button click in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58936169/1330560). But when i copy and paste that code i get an error saying  unexpected end of line input 30 file...Im very new to writing the code but im very good at following very specific instructions. Thanks for any help

Things ive tried but had no luck with....
"How to copy data to another sheet with a single button click in Google Sheets?", mentioned above and answered by @carlesgg97.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error message `unexpected end of line input 30 file` from the code in [How to copy data to another sheet with a single button click in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58936169/1330560).

**Lines 29 & 30**

```
database.appendRow([dateOfOrder, dateOfDelivery, agent, customer, itemName, 

   itemQuantity, itemPrice, itemQuantity * itemPrice]);
```

The reason for the error is that lines 29 and 30 are really one long line of code.

In the Editor the line can be broken up for the sake of clarity but... we have copied and pasted the code as text and the Editor thinks that it is two *unrelated* lines of code.

**Solution**

Join line 30 to the end of line 29. It should look something like this:

```
database.appendRow([dateOfOrder,dateOfDelivery,agent,customer,itemName,itemQuantity,itemPrice,itemQuantity*itemPrice]);
```

Comment: can you help explain to me more of the info i need to put into this code...For instance line 4 says YOUR_SOURCE_SHEET_NAME Ive tried the name i named the sheet and it still wont work. Also example 2  line 8 says get range and get value...Im so new to this i dont understand alot and i dont need to just need this code for business at a fence company. Thanks for any help and please dont feel bad if you want to talk to me like a 5 year old i understand lol

Comment: The script is intended for a single spreadsheet with multiple sheets/tabs. Data is copied _FROM_ one sheet/tab _TO_ another. `var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('YOUR_SOURCE_SHEET_NAME');` refers to the `FROM` sheet. Look at your spreadsheet for the name that you gave to this sheet and replace "YOUR_SOURCE_SHEET_NAME" with the actual sheet name. E.G. say the sheet is named "Quotes", then => `var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Quotes');`. Do the same thing for `var database = ss.getSheetByName('YOUR_DATABASE_SHEET_NAME');`

Comment: "Sheet1"=`sourceSheet`; details for one new "delivered order". Note: 1) cells B1:B8 = basic data; 2) three rows (11,12,13) of order items. "Sheet2"=`database`; three lines (one for each order item). Per row, 1st four data items come from cell "B1","B2","B8","B3" on `sourceSheet`, the rest are respective item details. Line 8=contents of cell B1:"Date of order"; Line 9=contents of cell B2:"Date of Delivery"; Line 10&11 ditto. Line 29 is part of an order row loop that appends the data for each item to `database`. After the loop, the data cells on `sourceSheet` are cleared (ready for a new order).